# Convert email string (text) to excel table

Tags: excel, vba, string, email

[email from which data needs to be captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzEvC.jpg)

I have an email string (as shown in the screenshot above) that I would like to convert to tables. The string comes in a specific format with fixed variables.
I would like to format this string in an excel table as shown below.

I have tried to convert this in VBA and able to extract this in string format something like below

> Package Summary:
>
> Client:  ABC
>
> Account Executive:  John Smith (JohnSmith@abc.com)
>
> Global Region:  North America
>
> Billing Party:  XYZ
>
> Party Responsible:  JKL
>
> Platform:  JAVA
>
> Platform Price (USD):  1,200
>
> Lead Time:  1 Week
>
> URL:  https://google,com
>
> Id:  00076q82uihef
>
> Response Id:  wsdiw3470972509

However, I am not able to convert this into an array through excel using text to columns or formulas.

It would be helpful if someone can guide in the right direction as to how this can be achieved with any manual intervention

[format in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgnBu.png)

Comment: What is your question though?  Exactly which part of this is giving you problems, and what have you tried to resolve that?  Please read [ask] and revise your question.

Comment: sorry about that, I have updated my query now

Comment: You can use VBA to get the text from the message, use `Split()` to produce an array of lines, then loop over the array checking each line for (eg) "Package Summary:" - when you get a match remove the line header and place the remaining text in the appropriate row/column.